# Using Comparable

Tags: java, foreach, comparable

Looking for assistance for following issue running into have following comparable method below that want to print largest value of goals scored from my Hockey Player ArrayList. I'm unable to store values from the for each loop successfully to pass it to the comparable method. Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

```
public static Comparable maximum(Comparable first, Comparable second, Comparable third) {
    if (first.compareTo(second) > 0) {
        if (first.compareTo(third) > 0) {
            return first;
        }
        return third;
    } else if (second.compareTo(third) > 0) {
        return second;
    }
    return third;
}
```

```
for (HockeyPlayer hp : hockeyPlayerList){
    int first = ((HockeyPlayer) hp).getGoalsScored(); {
        first = player1;
        first = player2;
        first = player3;
        first = player4;
    }
    System.out.println("The largest string is: " + Driver.maximum(player1,player2,player3));
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `java.util.Collections.sort(hockeyPlayerList);`?

Comment: "I'm unable to store values from the for each loop " - what for each loop?

Comment: the for loop is able to get goalsscored and output them all. But I want to pass those to comparable method written above. I Tried writing variable player 1, 2,3 & 4 but they don't pass to them.

Comment: Why must you use that method? It seems terribly constrained. Why not simply call compareTo on your items within the for loop itself? I fear that this might be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with "use java.util.Collections.sort(hockeyPlayerList);" comment, but just if you have to implement your own maximum...

Assuming your final goal is to be able to do this:

```
System.out.println("The largest string is: " + Driver.maximum(player1,player2,player3));
```

The function could looks like this:

```
public class Driver {

...

    public static Comparable maximum(Comparable... items) 
    {
        if(items.length ==  0)
        {
            return null; // no items to compare
        }

        Comparable currentMax = items[0];

        for(Comparable item : items)
        {
            // Update currentMax only if next element is larger
            currentMax = currentMax.compareTo(item) > 0 ? currentMax : item;
        }

        return currentMax;
    }
}
```

And inside your `Player` class you will have to have a `toString` function printing out a meaningful info about the player (`System.out.println` will call `toString` function for an instance of the `Player` class returned by a `maximum` function). Something like (I am giving and example, use actual fields you have in Player function):

```
public class Player {

    ...
    @Override
    public String toString()
    { 
        return this.getPlayerName() + ": " + this.getGoalsScored();
    }
}
```

Also the following fragment of the code makes no sense:

```
int first = ((HockeyPlayer) hp).getGoalsScored(); {
    first = player1;
    first = player2;
    first = player3;
    first = player4;
}
```

not sure what you were trying to accomplish there

Comment: I need to compare all four elements against each other and print it. Thank you for this will try it out.

Comment: the function compares any number of elements, if this is what you need